# how to use jetpack compose textinputservice for my custom compose

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose

I want get the keyboard input in my custom compose?But even i can't show a keybord.

Anyone know how to use it ?help please.

```
@Composable
fun SmsCodeCompose(onCompleted:(String)->Unit) {
    val textInputService = LocalTextInputService.current

    Text(text = "12112",
    modifier=Modifier.clickable {

            Timber.d("input service= $textInputService")
           val textInputSession = textInputService?.startInput(
                value = TextFieldValue(),
                imeOptions = ImeOptions(),
                onEditCommand = {it-> it.forEach{
                    Timber.d("$it")
                }
                },
                onImeActionPerformed = {}
            )
        textInputSession?.showSoftwareKeyboard()



    }.focusable(true))
```

Comment: I recently solved this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72322322/11883666