# Android Compose Faking Keyboard for specific textfields

Tags: android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, custom-keyboard, android-compose-textfield

I have a screen where some `textfields` I want to show a 'fake' keyboard. The keyboard should be able have as many buttons as I like and be displayed however I want. Just as shown below.

[image]

My question then is how do you accomplish something like this?

Is it possible to somehow **override** the interface to the keyboard so you **consume** the input and can display a 'fake' keyboard nd then remove the 'fake' keyboard when clicking on the back button on any other `textfield` which uses the normal keyboard?

Or do I have to create a custom `@Composable` or `TextView` with custom callbacks, and also render the text cursor manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement your own `TextInputService` or provide `null` to completely disable the default input service:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
  LocalTextInputService provides null // or myTextInputService 
) {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
    )
}
```

where `myTextInputService` is something like:

```
TextInputService(object : PlatformTextInputService {
    //TODO implement methods
}
```

Comment: How do you handle cursor position in TextField with custom keyboard?